# The first option for auto-import of TouchableOpacity is always from rn-gesture-handler rather than rn

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to have TouchableOpacity auto-import first from react-native, then from react-native-gesture-handler?

[image]

It's not just TouchableOpacity, other Touchables as well.